# LOST all Pod modules

Tags: swift, cocoapods

HELP! I restart the project, suddenly my project got an error because of not having modules. I did pod install and pod update, but the project can not read the pod? Something's happen with the pod files?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show us by posting what is the exact error.?

Comment: yes, I added showing error. thank you

Comment: you probably opened a project (`.xcodeproj`), you should always open workspace (`.xcworkspace` file) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify is your Pod file looks like the below

```
use_frameworks!

target 'YOUR_PROJECT' do
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Try to do `pod install`, `pod update` if required. Clean the **`Workspace`** and restart the `Xcode` if the issue still persists.

Comment: It really works. Thank you for your helps